# Unable to compile iOS React Native app with Firebase ML Kit Vision Text Detector

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-mlkit

I'm building an app with React Native that I've already "ejected" into its own native app project for iOS. I'm interested in using the new Firebase ML Kit Vision Text Detector for recognizing text in images using the *on-device* model, and I'm willing to write my own NativeModule wrapper for it (since it's so new, I don't see any existing wrappers in projects like react-native-firebase).

So, I used Cocoapods to bring in the Firebase dependencies, but when I try to compile the new workspace, I get the following linker error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLB28FLAGS_nosymbolize_stacktraceE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(examine_stack_b03c119c7358b452600b1afd20ca186c.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(utilities.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLB26FLAGS_symbolize_stacktraceE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(examine_stack_b03c119c7358b452600b1afd20ca186c.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(utilities.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLI9FLAGS_novE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(vlog_is_on_ec23571a5409c45b7e2ca681c18af4cb.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(vlog_is_on.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLI7FLAGS_vE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(vlog_is_on_ec23571a5409c45b7e2ca681c18af4cb.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(vlog_is_on.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLS13FLAGS_vmoduleE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(vlog_is_on_ec23571a5409c45b7e2ca681c18af4cb.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(vlog_is_on.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLB18FLAGS_nolog_prefixE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(logging_2072041cb58f7b92d4eb8dae33e75a0d.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(logging.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLB16FLAGS_log_prefixE in:
    /Users/francisli/Projects/clients/app/apptag-app/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector(logging_2072041cb58f7b92d4eb8dae33e75a0d.o)
    /Users/francisli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTag-arpnqvohzbwieueghdomemjvqvxt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(logging.o)
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

From what I've read on other cases of duplicate symbols errors in React Native projects, this is usually caused by including pods that depend on the React in addition to having the React project manually linked to the main app project (as it is initially set up after eject, along with other libraries linked using `react-native link`). However, that's not the case here- the only libraries I'm pulling in through the podfile are Firebase related, so I'm not sure how conflicts are happening.

Any insight from anyone- perhaps from the Firebase team working on the new ML Kit for iOS? Note that *I have not even written any code yet that references the framework*, I'm just trying to get the workspace configuration to compile. Here's the podfile for reference:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.3'

target 'App' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

And here's a screenshot of all the linked library projects in the main app project:

[image: Previously linked project dependencies]

Comment: So, even though the Podfile only references the Firebase libraries, it turns out there is a shared component between React and Firebase: glog (Google open source C++ logging utility), which is the source of the symbols referenced. I've tried removing glog source files from the React project config, in the hopes that it would then be linked to the glog symbols in the TextDetector framework, but I get a whole new set of _missing_ symbols after I do that... can someone from Google tell me what version of glog is being statically compiled into the TextDetector framework binary?!

Comment: I'm not familiar with React Native, but I tried adding React Native's CocoaPods (including glog) to ML Kit's Quick Start MLVision app (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlvision) following React Native's guide on integration with existing app (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).  I did not get any duplicate symbol error.  My ML Kit pod version is 0.9.0.  GoogleMobileVision pods (including GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector) is 1.3.2.  And glog version is 0.3.4. So I don't seem to be able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I only followed the React Native's guide up to installing all the CocoaPods, and then built the existing ML Kit Quick Start MLVision app without completing the steps for adding React Native to the app.  I did verify that both ML Kit's and React Native's pods (including glog) showed up in the xcode project navigator.  I then built and ran the app without issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comments- I will try to follow the same process you describe as well using the ML Kit sample app. However, if you did not actually complete the actual integration, then I think you will not see the issue because the error comes at the _linking_ step of the build process- if there are no references from the sample app to the React Native libraries, then the linker will not need to actually do anything with the compiled libraries, and will not show the error.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when applying ML kit to RN project. Here is the solution:

> Select Main target > Build Settings > Dead Stripping code = Yes

Hope it will get you through.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Worked for me after a similar error with Nearby Messages & React Native